# How do I open an image in sub-directory in Python?

Tags: python, directory, operating-system

```
def pickNprint(atri_list):
f_pick = (input("Choose a file by number (0-9):"))
while verify_entry(f_pick):
    print("Invalid Entry")
    f_pick = (input("Choose a file by number (0-9):"))
f_pick = int(f_pick)
f_pick = atri_list[f_pick]
filename = (f_pick[1])
#How to open a image in a subdirectory???
    openfile = Image.open(filename) #find image file - Need to access image_folder.. how?
    openfile.show()
    openfile.close()
```

I can't seem to be able to open a specific image in a subfolder(image_folder). I can only use this if the image file is in the working directory. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO! You need to specificy the folder from the directory. So, if it is in a sub-directory `images`. It would be as follows:

```
def pickNprint(atri_list):
    f_pick = (input("Choose a file by number (0-9):"))
    while verify_entry(f_pick):
        print("Invalid Entry")
        f_pick = int((input("Choose a file by number (0-9):")))
    filename = atri_list[f_pick][1]
    openfile = Image.open(r'images\'+filename) # change images to folder name
    openfile.show()
    openfile.close()
```

You also have some syntax issues which I have fixed and cleaned it up a little.